# Image Slider Not Working in android

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to make a text Slider and Image Slider in my code, text slider is working fine but Image Slider Not Appearing, i don't know why is it happening

Here is my code

Intro Frag

```
public class Intro extends Fragment {
    ViewPager imagePager, textPager;
    MammalAdapter mammalAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mammals_intro, container, false);

        forTextSlider(R.id.mammalIntroTextPager, view);
        forImageSlider(R.id.mammalIntroimagePager, view);

        return view;
    }

    private void forImageSlider(int pager, View view) {
        imagePager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(pager);
        int [] imageArray = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5,
                R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7, R.drawable.img8, R.drawable.img9, R.drawable.img10};
        mammalAdapter = new MammalAdapter(getActivity(), "img", imageArray);
        imagePager.setAdapter(mammalAdapter);
    }

    private void forTextSlider(int pager, View view) {
        textPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(pager);
        String [] mammalArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mammal_info);
        mammalAdapter = new MammalAdapter(getActivity(), "text", mammalArray);
        textPager.setAdapter(mammalAdapter);
    }

}
```

here is my Adapter Class

```
public class MammalAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    int img[]; String text[];
    String type;

    public MammalAdapter(Context context, String type, String[] text) {
        this.context = context;
        this.text = text;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public MammalAdapter(Context context, String type, int[] img) {

        this.context = context;
        this.img = img;
        this.type = type;
    }

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(type.equals("image"))
        {
            return img.length;
        }
        else if(type.equals("text")){
            return text.length;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view;
        if(type.equals("img"))
        {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mammal_img_item, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mammalImageItem);
            imageView.setImageResource(img[position]);
            container.addView(view);
            return view;
        }
        else if(type.equals("text")){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mammal_text_item, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mammalTextItem);
            textView.setText(text[position]);
            container.addView(view);
            return view;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

my Xml Layout

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/mammalIntroTextPager"/>

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/mammalIntroimagePager"/>
```

image item xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mammalImageItem"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

text item xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/whiteGrey"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mammalTextItem"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used [this](https://libraries.io/github/chan32167/AndroidImageSlider) library for image slider and it worked fine.

Comment: I think you use different type check on two place like if(type.equals("img")) and if(type.equals("image"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "img" instead of "image" in getCount() as below :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(type.equals("img"))
    {
        return img.length;
    }
    else if(type.equals("text")){
        return text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}
```